# Challenge-Response Application in E-banking

Tags: passwords, web-application, protocols, banks, challenge-response

Why is it important that Alice doesn't know *K*? What could happen if Alice knew *K*?

[image: http://postimg.org/image/k16aw2v3v/]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to comments from @Anders (thx!), I'm unsure if the password generator is a shared service or a personal authentication token like [digipass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digipass) or [SecureID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_SecurID).

**Password generator is a shared service**

In this situation, Alice can only get the signed response `H(R,K)` by proving to the password generator that she is Alice by presenting her PIN. If Alice knew `K`, then she could calculate `H(R,K)` on her own. This would allow Alice to pose as any user to Bob. The communication would be:

1. Alice --> Bob: `I'm Joe User`
2. Bob --> Alice: `R`
3. Alice --> Bob: `H(R,K)` which Alice calculated on her own

Alice has now successfully spoofed Joe User.

**Password generator is a personal authentication token**

In this situation, the token is being used to implement [2FA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication). The *something you know* factor is Alice's PIN, and the *something you have* factor is the authentication token. If Alice knows the `K` that is stored on her token, then she can compute `H(R,K)` on her own. This would allow her to log into the system using only a single factor, namely something that she knows. While there are two somethings: her PIN and `K`, it is still only the *something you know* factor. As the whole point of the token is to implement 2FA, `K` must be kept secret from Alice.

Comment: When I looked at the slide I just asumed that `K` was unique to Alice, but you seem to asume the opposite. I have no idea what assumption is correct.

Comment: @Anders, I think that if `K` is unique to Alice *and* known by both Alice and Bob, there's no reason for there to be a password generator service. To me, that diagram looks like a simplification of an SSO sign-on like SAML.

Comment: My first thought was that it was something like a [digipass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digipass), but again, I have no idea.

Comment: @Anders - Excellent point. I updated my answer. Thanks!